# Unreadable data from Bluetooth EEG device

Tags: android, arduino, character-encoding, android-bluetooth

I m trying to read data from ads1299 arduino module. I m able to connect device with my android application, but still get unreadable characters. I even tried decoding with UTF-8, US-ASCII, ISO-8859-1.

Here is my code

```
mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
int numBytes;
while (true) {
    try {
        // Read from the InputStream.
        numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
        String str = new String(mmBuffer, 0, numBytes);
        //String str = new String(mmBuffer, "UTF-8");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
        break;
    }
}
```

Sample encoded characters currently I m getting

����������D@����������Ѫ���w����w���$W���������W.����⪪��뚪���/U���

Comment: Unclear how this relates to Android as you should be checking data from the ADC on the Arduino side.